Why is there no InputRoot.JSON after propagating to subflow?
Is it normal behaviour that my JSON data gets removed after propagating to a subflow in IBM ACE 12 or is there a solution?
I built a small test integration where I have a compute node and a subflow and after propagating to the subflow there is no InputRoot.JSON to copy from. Both compute nodes have compute mode "LocalEnvironment and Message".
Here is my compute node in the message flow:
CREATE COMPUTE MODULE Run_JsonTests
    CREATE FUNCTION Main() RETURNS BOOLEAN
    BEGIN
        DECLARE refOutputData REFERENCE TO OutputRoot;
        CREATE FIELD OutputRoot.JSON.Data AS refOutputData IDENTITY(JSON.Object)Data;
        SET refOutputData.Test = 'Hello';
        PROPAGATE TO TERMINAL 'out1';
        SET OutputRoot.JSON.Data = InputRoot.JSON.Data;     
        RETURN FALSE;
    END;
END MODULE;

Here is my compute node in the subflow:
CREATE COMPUTE MODULE TestSubflow_Compute
    CREATE FUNCTION Main() RETURNS BOOLEAN
    BEGIN
        SET OutputRoot.JSON.Data = InputRoot.JSON.Data;
        SET OutputRoot.JSON.Data.SubflowTest = 'Testing';
        RETURN FALSE;
    END;    
END MODULE;

